# IICS Informatica - Not creating Flat File

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud

I am using Source - a query

```
select col1 from tab1 where exe_dt > sysdate;
```

**The above query returns no rows**

My Mapping
Source (Oracle 12c Table) -> (Passthough) Expression -> Target (Flat File (pipe delimited))

Even though there is no data i need to create the output flat file with nothing in it.

I am creating the target file as a dynamic file name at the run time with date concatenated - ABC_20210311_1a.csv.. the date of part of the file name changes everyday

appreciated if i can get any help

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting? Check the log of the mapping after the mapping is executed.